# Is the order of options for xcopy command important?

Tags: windows, xcopy

Is there a difference between these two lines?:

```
xcopy C:\source X:\destination /s /d
xcopy C:\source X:\destination /d /s
```

I've noticed that with the first one I also copy newer files in subfolder, with the second I don't. Only if the folder is newer then it's copied as well.

Can you confirm that the order on listing the option is important?

Comment: could you give more details, for example, windows version you are using, etc ?

Answer (score 1):

No, the order of the options should make no difference.

In general the order is only important regarding source and destination, or input and output. Internally, the program would read all the options you put, enable the corresponding actions, and then performe all them at once.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Means I need to experiment more! I'm trying to setup a backup with the task scheduler (windows 7); clearly I've done something not proper. Sergio